# Should I burst wrinklers before harvesting Bakeberries?

Tags: cookie-clicker

Bakeberries return 30 minutes of CPS when burst. Ten wrinklers halve your CPS. Are wrinklers making bakeberry returns lower?

Comment: Hey, I updated my answer with definite, confirmed information after unlocking Bakeberries myself.

Answer (score 2):

## No, you don't have to

Wrinklers are not affecting CPS, they are *withering* it, so it **doesn't affect the payout** of Bakeberries, Chocoroots, Crumbspores, Doughshrooms and other plants.

[image: a screenshot of Stats page from Cookie Clicker, showing Cookies per second (CPS), alongside with percentage of withered CPS]

There are at least three other values that rely on current CPS, one of them being the price of The Golden Switch. It requires a one hour worth of cookie production, and it stays the same going from 0 up to 12 wrinklers.

---

Note, however, that CPS *is* temporarily changed by Golden/Wrath Cookie effects; you may want to time your popping of Bakeberries after getting, say, Frenzy (Golden Cookie effect, x7) or Elder Frenzy (Wrath Cookie, x666) multiplier.